# How to detect Android Bluetooth connectGatt() auto-connect completion

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

(*** Edit #2: Trying to connect **multiple devices** ***)

I am using BluetoothDevice.connectGatt() with auto-connect set to true to connect to multiple devices:

```
bluetoothDevice1.connectGatt(context, true, BLGattCallback(context), BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE)
bluetoothDevice2.connectGatt(context, true, BLGattCallback(context), BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE)
```

(*** Edit # 1 ***)
I use onConnectionStateChange() in BluetoothGattCallback():

```
internal class BLGattCallback(val context: BTLeashService) : BluetoothGattCallback()        // Todo: Convert to LiveData
{
    override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int, newState: Int)
    {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState)

        val connectionStateChange = BLBluetoothManager.ConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState)
        BLBluetoothManager.connectionStateChange.postValue(connectionStateChange)
    }
```

(End Edit #1)

With this method I have to use a delay before executing my next connectGat() or else the previous one gets aborted.  Why is this?  I thought that it was not supposed to wait and just give a call back whenever it connects...

Is there a callback to let you know when the first connectGatt is complete so that I don't need an ad hock delay?

*** Edit #3 ***

By "first connectGatt is complete" I don't mean that a connection was made, only that I can now execute my next command without aborting the previous.

(End Edit #3)

Comment: That sounds like [`onConnectionStateChange()` on `BluetoothGattCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback?hl=en#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int,%20int)).

Comment: Sorry, yes I am using onConnectionStateChange() in BluetoothGattCallback.  I'll add that to the question...

Comment: OK, then you seem to already have the hook to find out that the connection request completed.

Comment: Yes, I do.  But it only works if I delay around 500 ms between connectGatt() calls.  I thought with auto-connect you shouldn't have to wait and can do a new command immediately after.  The delay is ad hock.  I'm looking for a callback for when I can issue a new connectGatt() call not for when the device connects.

Comment: If the device is off I never get a connection callback.  I want to know the moment I can make another connectGatt call if the device is off and doesn't generate a connection callback...

Comment: "If the device is off I never get a connection callback" -- that's interesting. I thought that you would get a callback but with a negative `status` value. I am more used to connecting to recently-discovered devices, so the device is almost always still on at the time.

Comment: No, with auto-connect it's not an error to fail to connect.  It just gives you a connect as soon as the device is detected...

Comment: Unfortunately there is not any API that informs whether the peripheral is unavailable. If it is crucial to check the presence of the peripheral you better scan for its presence first, then connect if it present.

Comment: @Kozmotronik so to be clear, my concern is not with whether or not the device is available but when can I execute my next connectGatt() command.  I need to establish an auto-connect to all the devices whether or not they actually connect or are even present.  'auto-connect' will establish the connection as soon it detects the device even if it's an hour latter.